# Performing deep search within object without using nested loops (lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to check if a value is found inside of an array contained deep in an object without having to use multiple for & for in loops. I want to know if there is an elegant way to achieve this. My first thought was to use lodash's _.includes, but it doesn't seem to iterate over the array in my sub-object.

```
//collection (i'm trying to reach person_id in the people array)
var tables = {
 12: {
  table_info: {
   name: 'Test'
  },
  people: [ //I want to check inside of this array
   {
    person_id: 123
   },
   {
    person_id: 233
   }
  ]
 }

//what i'm looping over to match up id's
var people = [
 {
  name: 'John Doe',
  id: 123
 },
 {
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  id: 245
 }
]

//loop
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) 
{
  if (_.includes(tables, people[i].id)) //would love a simple solution like this
  {
    console.log("match");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("no match");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this at all without using any libraries? Try creating the logic step-by-step. Besides, how would a library know you're searching through the `people` array for `person_id`s?

Answer (score 0):

why not create your own function and use it if you know the data structure?

```js
//collection
var tables = {
 12: {
    table_info: {
      name: 'Test'
    },
    people: [
     {
      person_id: 123
     },
     {
      person_id: 233
     }
    ]
  }
};

var peopleToFind = [
 {
  name: 'John Doe',
  id: 123
 },
 {
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  id: 245
 }
];

function findPeopleInTables(people, tables){
  let peopleFound = [];
  for (var key in tables) {
    // to make sure it doesnt come from prototype
    if (tables.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      tables[key].people.forEach(function (person){
          peopleToFind.forEach(function(personToFind){
            if (person.person_id === personToFind.id){
              peopleFound.push(personToFind);
            }
          });
        });
    }
  }
  return peopleFound;
}

let foundPeople = findPeopleInTables(peopleToFind, tables);
foundPeople.forEach(function(person){
  console.log('found "' + person.name + '" with id ' + person.id);
});
```

also you can search in objects using recursive methods :

```js
function findValueInObject(value , object){
    let type = typeof(object);
    if(type !== 'string'  && type !== 'number'  && type !== 'boolean'){
        for (var key in object) {
            // to make sure it doesnt come from prototype
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if( findValueInObject(value , object[key])){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(object === value){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//collection
var tables = {
 12: {
    table_info: {
      name: 'Test'
    },
    people: [
     {
      person_id: 123
     },
     {
      person_id: 233
     }
    ]
  }
};

var peopleToFind = [
 {
  name: 'John Doe',
  id: 123
 },
 {
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  id: 245
 }
];

peopleToFind.forEach(function(person){
    if(findValueInObject(person.id, tables)){
        console.log('matched: ' + person.id + ' '+ person.name);
    }
});
```